# Flutter error when trying to connect to Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, ubuntu

I am trying to connect to the Firebase, but when i import firebase_core inside main.dart, i cannot run the app. When i do flutter run, assembly debug fails with weird long error.

```
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_platform_interface-4.5.3/lib/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:246:7: Error: 'bathrow' isn't a type.
[   +1 ms]       bathrow PlatformException(
[        ]       ^^^^^^^
[        ] ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_platform_interface-4.5.3/lib/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:246:15: Error: Expected ';' after this.
[        ]       bathrow PlatformException(
[        ]               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[        ] ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_platform_interface-4.5.3/lib/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:246:32: Error: This requires the experimental 'records'
language feature to be enabled.
```

I have followed tutorial and have correctly configured build.gradle files ( i think). Also i have this imports:

```
firebase_database: ^10.0.15
  firebase_core: ^2.7.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.4
```

Maybe it is specific to my environment. I am on Ubuntu linux.

I tried switching from snap to non-snap flutter, no affect. I tried changing version of firecore, i tried changing ext.kotlin_version but nothing changes. When i run app without importing firecore, it works, but i need firecore.

Answer (score 1):

Is your app being run on Android/iOS or Linux? Because I see from pub.dev that firebase_core does not have Linux support (at least not yet).

Comment: It has been running on Android. I am developing it on Linux, but it shouldn't be a problem as I recall. Sorry for the late reply, I didn't get a notification.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the error was inside firebase_core repo, there was a typo on line 246 saying bethrow instead of throw. I changed it and it fixed my problem. I went on to their gihub to fork it and add contribution, but it seems like it is fixed already.